# Limiting search to a site collection NOT working

Tags: search, search-results

I am trying to limit my search results to a specific site collection,  but it is NOT working.

I have the following configuration:

1- Root site collection

2- /sites/teamsitecollection

3- /sites/teamsitecollection/searchcenter

Basically I am trying to configure search center to NOT display any results from the Root Site collection when a user queries from from /sites/teamsitecollection.

what i did.

1. Configured the search settings /sites/teamsitecollection to point to the following results page: /sites/teamsitecollection/SearchCenter/results.aspx.
2. On the /sites/teamsitecollection configured a **RESULT SOURCE** with the following query transform: **{searchTerms} Path={SiteCollection.URL}***

However this configuration continues to display results from the root site collection. any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I am facing the same issue. I just made it work with a workaround by specifying the site collection URL as a part of the query. This is not a generic approach that will work for all the site collection but as per my requirement, it works.

**Solution:**
Specify the "*Append Text To Query*" of the core results webpart
Path:"*/sites/teamsitecollection"

> '*' is used so it can work in different environments like dev > stage >prod

Ref: [MSDN Blog](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sharepoint_strategery/2014/07/31/sharepoint-search-quirks-query-variables/)

Hope this helps.